# Toolbar(?) underneath navigation bar - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I'm wondering how one goes about implementing something like the following:

[image]

The grey bar underneath the navigation bar that contains 2 buttons, 'Expense' and 'Income'.  Can anyone point me to a resource or explain how you implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the second bar is a Toolbar. Just place a Toolbar underneath the navigation bar. What problems you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Segmented Control (UISegmentedControl) in a Toolbar (UIToolbar) that's placed below the navigation bar.

Comment: XCode doesn't seem to let me place it there if I'm using a UICollectionViewController. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

From this layout, my guess at the implementation is:

- Top Level: `UITabViewController`
- Selected Tab: `MyHistoryViewController` (subclass of `UIViewController` - or possibly a `UITableViewController` - placed inside a `UINavigationController`)
- `MyHistoryViewController` can be laid out in Interface Builder (build into Xcode these days) with a `UIToolbar` using a `UISegmentedControl` (or your custom toolbar that looks like that above) above a `UITableView`

The [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a useful resource.